# How to use openstreet map in iOS with custom map Server, Swift any Libraray?

Tags: android, ios, swift, openstreetmap, mktileoverlay

We have our **own open street map server** which is `maintain` by our company. for both **Android** and **iOS** we are planning to use this **Map Server** which is like

"http://maps.mycompanyname.com/osmtiles/15/23655/15748.png."

For Android they have amazing [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) for all displaying, routing and all those things. it works perfectly. But for **iOS** we couldn't find a **such library**. we are trying to do this with **MKMapView** with `custom tiles`, **but doesn't success**.

Features love to have,

1. show any given location with markers.
2. show multiple marker points.
3. navigation support (optional)

Hope any Guidance for this from you. Please help me with this.

Comment: Please see here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Apple_iOS#Libraries_for_developers

Comment: yep, @Thommy went through most of it . but didn't get any success. looked if anyone has the experience with any library or way to do this. anyway thank you and have a great day sir .

Comment: In this case state a bit more about what features you need and why your current solution is not working.

Comment: @Thommy added features that I wish to have. most of the libraries are support only for their Servers endpoints. as an example Mapbox.

Answer (score 0):

It's some years since I've done it, but can't you still have a webview within an iOS app and have e.g. Leaflet in there?  That can definitely display the tiles you're interested in.